# toggle color change of two arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want one arrow color to be changed if it's clicked and stay changed until the other arrow is clicked.

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Do you have any advice how I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use javascript to get the action you desire. I would suggest you use the [jquery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript library if you are unfamiliar with javascript. Here is an example of code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('span').click(function(){
         // Set all spans to default
        $('span').css('background-color', '#333');
         // Set clicked to green
        $(this).css('background-color', '#10fd01');
    });

});
```

```css
span{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: #333
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>arrow</span>
<span>arrow</span>
```

Comment: @winixxee, Does your arrow button changes color when you change its background-color?

Answer (score 1):

Just a modified version of "magreenberg" post. I think below is a better approach to this problem.

```js
$('.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-top.col-md-12').click(function(){
        $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-top.col-md-12').css('color', '#333');
  $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-bottom.col-md-12').css('color', '#333');
        $(this).css('color', '#10fd01');
    });
 $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-bottom.col-md-12').click(function(){
        $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-top.col-md-12').css('color', '#333');
  $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-bottom.col-md-12').css('color', '#333');
         // Set clicked to green
        $(this).css('color', '#10fd01');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```